# JavaMailSender: Can i share CreateMimeMessage result between different sessions?

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I have a unsual mail setup at my company where we have a main SMTP mail server and a backup SMTP mail server.
I'm currently using spring-wrapper `JavaMailSender` ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html)), which allows me to use `createMimeMessage()`, fill in all my message information, and then send it with the `send(MimeMessage message)` method.

My issue is that the smtp main server might fail. In this case I need to send the email through the backup mail server. But it will only fail in the send method, with the message already "built".

I currently just reuse the same `MimeMessage` and pass it to a different instance of JavaMail with different setup, it looks like it is working, but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it as the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html#createMimeMessage--) says the MimeMessage is created for this instance:

`CreateMimeMessage(): Create a new JavaMail MimeMessage for the underlying JavaMail Session of this sender. Needs to be called to create MimeMessage instances that can be prepared by the client and passed to send(MimeMessage)`

And:

`send(MimeMessage mimeMessage): Send the given JavaMail MIME message. The message needs to have been created with createMimeMessage().`

Can I exchange the `MimeMessages` created with `createMimeMessage()` between different `JavaMailSender` instances ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: You can create an instance of MimeMessage, as a static (a singleton)  and then pass it to all the instances you create, if needed.

Comment: What does the singleton bring ? I would still have a `MimeMessage` created by one `JavaMailSender` and sent by another `JavaMailSender`, am I wrong ?

Comment: No. The idea here is to create an instance of a `MimeMessage`, and then you can share this instance between different `JavaMailSenders`.

Comment: But the `MimeMessage` is created by one of these instance, I do not create it myself. Could I use it with the other instance ? It looks like it's working currently.